# How to add legend/label in python animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add a legend in a python animation, like the `line.set_label()` below. It is similar to `plt.plot(x,y,label='%d' %*variable*)`.

However, I find that codes do not work here. The animation only shows lines changing but no label or legend available. How can I fix this problem?

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
 from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(0, 100))

N = 3
lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)]


def init():    
    for line in lines:
        line.set_data([], [])
    return lines

def animate(i):
    for j,line in enumerate(lines):
        line.set_data([0, 2], [10*j,i])
        line.set_label('line %d, stage %d'%(j,i))
    return lines

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You can look through here http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert on matplotlib at all, but in the [Double Pendulum animation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) they display texts which changes, and this leads to some variations which can help you.

To get legends with the actual color of the lines, you can either change the initial setting `lines` to:

```
lines = [plt.plot([], [], label = 'line {}'.format(i))[0] for i in range(N)]
```

or add a `line.set_label()` to the `for` loop in the `init()` function. Both these seem to work as expected. At least if you add `plt.legend(loc="upper left")` right before `plt.show()`.

However the `set_label` doesn't work within the `animate()` function, but according to the linked animation you can use specific text fields added to the animation, and that seems to work nicely. Add the following code after initialisation of `lines`:

```
texts = [ax.text(0.80, 0.95-i*0.05,  '', transform=ax.transAxes) for i in range(N)]
```

And change `animate()` to be:

```
def animate(i):
    for j in range(N):
        lines[j].set_data([0, 2], [10*j,i]) #, label="hei {}".format(i))
        texts[j].set_text('line %d, stage %d'%(j,i))
    return lines
```

This places the text close to the upper right corner, and is updated for each animation step. Since the lines still have their legend displayed, you possibly simplify into one text only displaying the stage. But I leave the fine tuning of messages to your discretion.

### Addendum: Extend Line2D

Another alternative could *possibly* be to extend `lines.Line2D` and use these lines in your animation, something similar to [this article](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/line_with_text.html). Not sure if this would work with animation, but if you can't get the above to work, this might be worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

you must return the legend in your animation function for it to be rendered.
Try this, instead :

```
legend = plt.legend()
def animate(i):
    for j,line in enumerate(lines):
        line.set_data([0, 2], [10*j,i])
        line.set_label('line %d, stage %d'%(j,i))
    legend.remove()
    legend = plt.legend()
    return lines + [legend]
```

You should also include the same code in your init function, init is used when resizing the window, otherwise the legend will disappear when resizing

Comment: Are you missing a `global legend`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this minimum working example below. The handle of legend `hlegend` consist of handles of text `htext`, so we can update `htext` content in the `hf_frame`.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
N0 = 20
xdata = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
omega = np.linspace(1, 4, N0)
ydata = np.sin(omega[:,np.newaxis]*xdata)
hline0, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata[0], label=f'omega={omega[0]:.3f}')
hlegend = ax.legend(loc='upper right')
def hf_frame(ind0):
    hline0.set_data(xdata, ydata[ind0])
    label_i = f'{omega[ind0]:.3f}'
    # hline0.set_label(label_i) #doesn't help
    htext = hlegend.get_texts()[0]
    htext.set_text(label_i)
    return hline0,htext
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, hf_frame, frames=N0, interval=200)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This example doesn't work for me. When I run the code, I get `UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely unintended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable that exists for as long as you need the Animation.`

Comment: oops, I forgot to add `plt.show()` at the end